# How to output mysql query to a html table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

need your help again.

So I have a query, with multiple variables which I have to output to a table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          zi.zile,
          ore.ora AS ore,
          materii.materie
        FROM
          zi LEFT JOIN  orar ON zi.id = orar.id_zi 
          LEFT JOIN  ore ON ore.id = orar.id_ora 
          LEFT JOIN  nume_scoli ON nume_scoli.id = orar.id_scoala 
          LEFT JOIN  materii_pe_clase ON materii_pe_clase.id_scoala = nume_scoli.id 
          LEFT JOIN  clase ON materii_pe_clase.id_clasa = clase.id AND orar.id_clasa = clase.id
          LEFT JOIN  elevi ON elevi.id_clasa = materii_pe_clase.id_clasa 
          LEFT JOIN  materii ON materii.id = orar.id_materie 
                WHERE clase.`id`=1

            ORDER BY zi.`zile`, ore.`id` ASC
```

and the result of this query looks like this :

[image]

Now this is what I`ve done in php:

```
  $oraru = "the query from up this page ";
    $gaseste_oraru = mysql_query($oraru);
    $numar_orar = mysql_num_rows($oraru);
  if($numar_orar==0)
    {
      echo "Orarul nu este disponibil momentan.";
    }
  else 
    {
    while($randorar=mysql_fetch_array($gaseste_oraru))
    {
        $ziorar = $randorar['zile'];
        $oraorar = $randorar['ore'];
        $materieorar = $randorar['materie'];
}
}
```

This is the table I want to populate with data from the database:

[image: table]

Here you have the code of the table:

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           Orar
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Luni
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            Marti
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Miercuri
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Joi
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            Vineri
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            8:00 - 9:00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <select>
  <option>Mate</option>
  <option>Romana</option>
  <option>Geogra</option>
</select>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
  <option>Mate</option>
  <option>Romana</option>
  <option>Geogra</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
  <option>Mate</option>
  <option>Romana</option>
  <option>Geogra</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <select>
  <option>Mate</option>
  <option>Romana</option>
  <option>Geogra</option>
</select>
                        </td>

                             <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            9:00 - 10:00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                             <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            10:00 - 11:00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                             <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            11:00 - 12:00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                       <td>
                            rand 1
                        </td>
                </table>
            </div>
```

**NEVERMIND THE DROPDOWNS, I WON`T USE THEM!**

Do you have any idea how to populate it, BUT if nothing exists for an interval (e.g Luni 8:00-9:00), then write nothing in the table?

EDIT

Here is what I tried :

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
   <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           Orar
                        </td>
                        <?php
  {
      $oraru = "the query from up this page";
    $gaseste_oraru = mysql_query($oraru);

    while($randorar=mysql_fetch_array($gaseste_oraru))
    {
        $ziorar = $randorar['zile'];
        $oraorar = $randorar['ore'];
        $materieorar = $randorar['materie'];
        echo "<td>";
        echo $randorar['zile'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $randorar['ore'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $randorar['materie'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }//sfarsit while
```

Here is the result:

[image: bad]

Any ideas?

Comment: Put the table code in the while loop and generate the table on the fly.

Comment: That is what I tried to do, but it doesn`t seem to work Mihai. I`m from romania too :)

Comment: Mi-am dat seama,salut.Here is an example with a table generated from php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050558/create-table-with-php-and-populate-from-mysql?rq=1

Comment: salut! Hmm...let me try it again. I did this before, but some time has passed since the last time i did it, so I probably forgot how. I`ll try and come back to post the solution (if it will work). Multumesc !

Comment: i see that you just generate them and you dont use them to echo them in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is the solution:

```
 $oraru = "
        SELECT DISTINCT
              zi.zile,
              ore.ora AS ore,
              materii.materie
            FROM zi 
              LEFT JOIN  orar ON zi.id = orar.id_zi 
              LEFT JOIN  ore ON ore.id = orar.id_ora 
              LEFT JOIN  nume_scoli ON nume_scoli.id = orar.id_scoala 
              LEFT JOIN  materii_pe_clase ON materii_pe_clase.id_scoala = nume_scoli.id 
              LEFT JOIN  clase ON materii_pe_clase.id_clasa = clase.id AND orar.id_clasa = clase.id
              LEFT JOIN  elevi ON elevi.id_clasa = materii_pe_clase.id_clasa 
              LEFT JOIN  materii ON materii.id = orar.id_materie 
              WHERE clase.`id`=1
            ORDER BY  ore.`id`, zi.`zile` ASC";
      $gaseste_oraru = mysql_query($oraru);
    $rows = array();
    while($randorar=mysql_fetch_array($gaseste_oraru))
    {        
        $ziorar = $randorar['zile'];
        $oraorar = $randorar['ore'];
        $materieorar = $randorar['materie'];
        if(!isset($rows[$oraorar])){
            $rows[$oraorar] = array();
        }
        $rows[$oraorar][$ziorar] = $materieorar;        
    }//sfarsit while

    ?>
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>Orar</td><td>Luni</td><td>Marti</td><td>Mercuri</td><td>Joi</td><td>Vineri</td>
        </tr>
    <?php

        foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
          if(!isset($row['Luni'])) $row['Luni'] = '&nbsp;';//incase no data from database
          if(!isset($row['Marti'])) $row['Marti'] = '&nbsp;';//incase no data from database
          if(!isset($row['Miercuri'])) $row['Miercuri'] = '&nbsp;';//incase no data from database
          if(!isset($row['Joi'])) $row['Joi'] = '&nbsp;';//incase no data from database
          if(!isset($row['Vineri'])) $row['Vineri'] = '&nbsp;';//incase no data from database
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
             foreach ($row as $day => $study) {
               echo "<td>$study</td>";    
             }
             echo "</tr>";
         } 
     ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I figured it out with some help from a friend!

Thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is for you to `ORDER BY ore.id, zi.zile`.

Since you iterate row by row, and not column by column, you will be able to optimize your `while` loop.

Comment: I tried like that also. But i couldn`t decide so I used that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to do something like this

```
$xarr=Array();
$xcols=Array();
while($randorar=mysql_fetch_array($gaseste_oraru))
{
    $xcols[$randorar['zile']]++;
    $xarr[$randorar['ore']][$randorar['zile']] = $randorar['materie']
} 
echo "<tr><th>orar</th>";
foreach(array_keys($xcols) as $x)
   echo '<th>'.$x.'</th>';
echo "</tr>\n";

foreach($xarr as $key=>$y){
   echo '<tr><th>'.$key.'</th>';
   foreach(array_keys($xcols) as $x)
      echo '<td>'.$y[$x].'</td>';
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Luni in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 581, $xcols[$randorar['zile']]++;, as I don`t have a number in there, but a string "Luni" or "Marti" or so on

Comment: by deleting the line, the code works, but only for the interval (8-9, 9-10), not for the data in the table for each days...I dont know how to work with arrays as good as I know how to work with variables. Thank you for the time !

Comment: it generates rows and cols only for data returned from your query. if you need to generate whole table you have to fill your arrays by youself: $xarr=Array('8-9'=Array(),'9-10'=Array(),'11-12'=Array()); and for $xcols=Array('Luni','Marti',.....). About $xcols[$randorar['zile']]++, you may delete it if you fill $xcols, or you can try replace it with $xcols[$randorar['zile']]=1;