# How Can I Show Rows With Multi Select?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to show my records multi selectable. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtqLF.png
Then i will make buttons for "delete selected items", "edit selected items" e.t.c.
So, how can ?

Comment: Please try to be more elaborate. Add some of the details here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check uncheck All checkboxes with another single checkbox use jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504643/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-another-single-checkbox-use-jquery)

Comment: Have a look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/

Comment: Check your solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050558/create-table-with-php-and-populate-from-mysql

Comment: I think I'm confused today. It was really very easy problem. Thanks for your replies guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your check box as array(`name="check_list[]"`). So it will store multiple vales on it. Then use `foreach` loop and do your needs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="CSS"><label>CSS</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="HTML"><label>HTML</label><br/>
```

as well as check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pzCcE/2/) too

Comment: Thank you man, it is what i'm searching for.